# AJAX Search results to not dynamically update with user search input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, livesearch

I have made a AJAX Search field allowing me to search my database with the inputted value, the results will be shown in a list below the input field.

The search only updates once the input has been entered and then cleared rather than updating after each and every key input, I know the connection and page setup is fine because after I input text into the field it displays "TEST" below however only when I clear the input field! It should be searching after every key input.

I can't find any mistakes in the code, but if someone can see a reason why it is not updating on every key stroke, it would be much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<form>
<input autocomplete="off" name="search_text" id="search_text" type="text" placeholder="search...">
<div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#search_text').keyup(function() {
                var txt = $(this).val();
                if(txt != '')
                {

                }
                else 
                {
                    $('#result').html('');
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"sections/fetch.php",
                        method:"post",
                        data:{search:txt},
                        dataType:"text",
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                            $('#result').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $cameras = mysqli_connect($xxx, $xxx, $xxx, $xxx);
?>


<?php 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM models WHERE model LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%'";
$result = mysqli_query($cameras, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "TEST" . '<br>';
    }


} else {
    echo 'Data Not Found';
}

?>
```

Comment: the condition `if(txt != '')` is wrong. it should be the opposite ` if(txt === '') {} else {// make ajax request}`

Comment: Thats pefect, didn't realise that, thank you !